# Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer constructor throws file not found exception

Tags: c#, uwp, sapi

A lot of users for my UWP app are hitting `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` in the `Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer..ctor()`

The code is calling the default constructor of `Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer`

```
private SpeechSynthesizer _speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
```

I have got the following stack trace for one user, others also report similar stack trace. I don't hit this exception on my local machine so not able to debug further.

Any idea how can I debug this further or fix it?

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
The system cannot find the file specified.

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ActivateInstance(String) + 0x17b
   at Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer..ctor() + 0x1c
   at SampleReader.TtsHelper.TtsHelper..ctor(TtsData, MediaElement) + 0x6f
   at SampleReader.UIPages.Reader.<InitializeReader>d__45.MoveNext() + 0xfb
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() + 0x21
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0(Object) + 0x1e
   at System.Action`1.Invoke(T) + 0x28
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore() + 0x33
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed(Int32, RuntimeTypeHandle) + 0x21
   at __Interop.ComCallHelpers.Call(__ComObject, RuntimeTypeHandle, Int32) + 0xb8
   at __Interop.ForwardComStubs.Stub_19[TThis](__ComObject, Int32) + 0x24
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelper.<.ctor>b__17_1(Object, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs) + 0x3d
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() + 0x21
   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.ApplicationLifecycleHelper.<.ctor>b__17_1(Object, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs) + 0x75
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object, TEventArgs) + 0x2e
   at __Interop.Intrinsics.HasThisCall__24[TArg0](Object, IntPtr, Object, TArg0) + 0x36
   at Sample Reader!<BaseAddress>+0x110b4f0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code above, and encountered the same exception(file not found).

You could let your users check if the **Speech Recognize** feature is enabled in local machine(type **Speech Recognize** in **Search** box). And check if the language used(such as **English(United States)**) enables **Speech**(Open **Setting > Time & Language > Language > Preferred languages**, click **English(United States) > Options**).
If the **Speech Recognize** feature is not supported, you need to enable it.

There are two way you could try to enable the feature:

1. Find your language in **Language** (**Settings > Time & Language**), click **Options**, click **Download** button under **Speech** to enable the **Speech feature** for the language.
2. Open **Speech** (**Settings > Time & Language**), click **Add voices** under **Manage voices**, select needed language to **Add**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to answer this. I have few questions - 
[1.] Searching 'Speech Recognize' does not yield any result - https://imgur.com/8P4Sb93 
[2.] From your description it looks like if no TTS voice is downloaded then this error occurs, so downloading any TTS voice should help? Coz I could not find 'Speech Recognize feature' anywhere?
[3.] What version of Windows do you have, coz I created a fresh Win 10 1909 VM and it had the TTS voice installed for the default language (or did you do anything to remove the TTS voices)?

Comment: I’d either check SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice or SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.Count to see if there are any installed voices.

Comment: The OS build is 19041.508, and the Version is 2004 in my machine. My machine has been reset and I never remove my TTS voices.
The reason why you cannot search for the feature is that the word I gave was spelled wrong. The correct spelling is **Speech Recognition**. I am very sorry for this. You could also find the **Windows Speech Recognition** by **Control Panel** referring to the **Help your PC recognize your voice** in the [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-voice-recognition-in-windows-10-83ff75bd-63eb-0b6c-18d4-6fae94050571).

Comment: You should ensure the Speech(**Settings > Time & Language > Language > Preferred languages > English > Options > Speech**) of your language(such as English) is enabled.